# Prevent IOS WebView from caching images

Tags: caching, ios5, webview

**Situation:**
A native IOS5 App downloads a website from FTP to local storage and a webview displays the downloaded page. If there is a new version on the FTP-Server, the App will automaticly download the new version and override the old one in the local storage. Now the webview should load the new version.

**Problem:**
When the new version overwrides the old version, the name of some images will be the same. Now the webview will load every image from cache insteat from filesystem. -.-

**Question:**
Is there a possibility to prevent the webview loading all images from cache or clear the whole cache? What I cant do is changing the html or js of the downloaded page. So the approache to add a timestamp behinde every image (test.img?timestamp=23444) cant be done. The change has to be done in the IOS App.

What ive tryed already but failed:

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];

NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:nil];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[ftpPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"index.html"]];

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval:1.0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest: urlRequest];

[webView stopLoading];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[webView reload];
webView.delegate = self;
```

Thank you so much for any help, i dont get it.

Cya Nando